# How to create javascript Request Object with Body type as form-data file

Tags: javascript, typescript, rest, rxjs

[image]

I am trying to code POST REST API request as shown in the above Postman screenshot.

Here is my code:

```
import { fromFetch } from 'rxjs/fetch';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

interface FetchRequest<TBody> {
  method?: FetchMethod;
  body?: TBody;
  headers?: FetchHeaders;
  isBlobRequest?: boolean;
}

export const request = <TBody extends BodyInit = BodyInit>(
  url: string,
  fetchRequest?: FetchRequest<TBody>,
  contentType: string
) => {
  const { method = 'POST', body, headers } = fetchRequest ?? {};
  const { dispatch } = createStore();
  let request = new Request(`${domainUrl}${url}`, {
    method,
    body: body ? body : null,
    headers: {
      ...headers,
      'Content-type': contentType ,
    },
    credentials: 'include',
  });
  
  return fromFetch(request).pipe(
    switchMap((response: Response) => {
      if (response.status === SUCCESS_CODE) {
        if (isBlobRequest) {
          return response.blob();
        }
        return response.text();
      } else if (response.status === USER_SESSION_EXPIRED_CODE) {
        dispatch(authAsyncActions.setSessionExpired());
        throw response;
      } else {
        // This triggers error-handling and allows us to inspect the entire
        // error response including its status and body
        throw response;
      }
    })
  );
};


const callUploadAPI = (file) => {

      let formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('file', file);
      request(`urlUploadFile`, { method: 'POST', body: formData}, 'application/vnd.ms-excel')

}
```

In above code I am using fromFetch of "rxjs/fetch" to call the POST REST API and passing "Request" object in fromFetch().
Request interface is inside typescript as per the below screenshot.
[image]

Backend is Python flask server and on the backend side in Python code I am using 
 `file = request.files['file']` 
 to get the file which is working when I call the API through Postman but when I call the API through frontend code it is not getting file.


How can I set the Request "Body" type as "form-data" and "KEY" type as File in frontend code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're explicitly setting the `Content-type` to `application/vnd.ms-excel`, but you don't need to set this header

As far as I know, if the `body` of a fetch request is a `FormData` object, the browser automatically sets the content type header to `multipart/form-data`

Comment: I removed Content-type and it works now. Thanks a lot @Drenai.

Comment: Nice one. I actually learned a lot from this question myself 